# Git repo update date and time

Tags: git

Is it possible to get the date and time when my git repository was updated from the remote repo. Currently I use "`repo sync`" and "`git pull --rebase`" to update my local repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git rev-list --format=format:'%ai' --max-count=1 `git rev-parse HEAD`
```

From https://gist.github.com/bitrut/1494315